# How to subtract one dictionary from another?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

**How can we subtract two dictionaries yielding a third dictionary with the differences?**

I've a dictionary: `Dictionary<string, int>()`:

```
+-------+----+
| alex  | 10 |
| liza  | 10 |
| harry | 20 |
+-------+----+
```

From this dictionary, I would like to *subtract* this dictionary:

```
+-------+---+
| alex  | 5 |
| liza  | 4 |
| harry | 1 |
+-------+---+
```

The result I'm looking for would be:

```
+-------+----+
| alex  |  5 |
| liza  |  6 |
| harry | 19 |
+-------+----+
```

**How can we subtract two dictionaries yielding a third dictionary with the differences?**

Comment: Can we assume they are using default comparers (e.g. not case insensitive)?

Comment: sure, definitely thank you

Comment: How robust does this code need to be? I assume you want to subtract the corresponding entry in dictionary #2 (e.g. with the same keys)?

Comment: @theMayer we can assume that they will *always* have the same keys

Comment: You may find  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812545/how-do-i-sum-values-from-two-dictionaries-in-c worth reading (since some of the approaches will also work for you).

Comment: I know in your example you the keys match on both dictionaries. But what should happen if they don't? What if there are extra in the first or extra in the second? Or both?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes indeed, it'd be nice to be able to handle those cases

Comment: It is very hard to reconcile both `we can assume that they will always have the same keys` and `yes indeed, it'd be nice to be able to handle those cases`. Please be **clear** in your requirements.

Comment: May be it's a good idea not to do this at all? Dictionary is not meant for this kind of access pattern. Why not just get the difference on demand when it's needed using a regular look up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> we can assume that they will always have the same keys

In this case, it's very easy with a simple foreach loop. Full example:

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dict1.Add("alex", 10);
dict1.Add("liza", 10);
dict1.Add("harry", 20);

var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dict2.Add("alex", 5);
dict2.Add("liza", 4);
dict2.Add("harry", 1);

var dict3 = new Dictionary<string, int>(dict1.Count);   // Thanks, @mjwills!
foreach (var pair in dict1)
{
    dict3.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value - dict2[pair.Key]);
}
```

Or using the [`ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary) method instead of a loop:

```
var dict3 = dict1.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value - dict2[p.Key]);
```

Comment: whats the benefit of dynamically allocating the size of the dictionary, is in `new Dictionary<string, int>(dict1.Count);` ?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' That was suggested by mjwills because it increases the performance. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2__ctor_System_Int32_): _"If the size of the collection can be estimated, specifying the initial capacity eliminates the need to perform a number of resizing operations while adding elements to the Dictionary<TKey,TValue>."_

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed But requesting a large allocation upfront can also hinder performance due to sub-optimal allocations. Lots of the time, it's just better to let the runtime decide.

Comment: @swdon But the contradicts with the quote from the documentation in my comment above. Either way, one could try to measure both and determine which one is faster for each case (large dictionaries and many small ones).

Answer (score 2):

If there are extra keys in either or both dictionaries then this code does the job of merging them together:

```
var dict3 =
    dict1
        .Concat(dict2)
        .Select(x => x.Key)
        .Distinct()
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Key = x,
            Value1 = dict1.TryGetValue(x, out int Value1) ? Value1 : 0,
            Value2 = dict2.TryGetValue(x, out int Value2) ? Value2 : 0,
        })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value1 - x.Value2);
```

This still works with your original dictionaries, but if you had this:

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    { "alex", 10 },
    { "liza", 10 },
    { "harry", 20 },
};

var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    { "alex", 5 },
    { "liza", 4 },
    { "mike", 1 },
};
```

Then it outputs a dictionary that looks like this:

```
new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    { "alex", 5 },
    { "liza", 6 },
    { "harry", 20 },
    { "mike", -1 },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way  to do this is via a simple foreach loop.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var first = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "alex", 10 }, { "liza", 10 }, { "harry", 20 } };
            var second = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "alex", 5 }, { "liza", 4 }, { "harry", 1 } };
            var third = first.ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key, entry => entry.Value);

            foreach (var item in first)
            {
                third[item.Key] = first[item.Key] - second[item.Key];
                Console.WriteLine(third[item.Key]);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

... or via linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var first = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "alex", 10 }, { "liza", 10 }, { "harry", 20 } };
            var second = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "alex", 5 }, { "liza", 4 }, { "harry", 1 } };
            var third = first.ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key, entry => entry.Value - second[entry.Key]);

            foreach (var item in first)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(third[item.Key]);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```